# Small white line flashing top of screen Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, flash

After installing Ubuntu 14.04 on my ACER V3-572G with a Nvidia Geforce 840M alongside Windows 8.1, I get a small white line flashing (every few seconds) on top of my screen. Ubuntu works fine without any problem and there is no additional driver to install.

I saw people have similar problems but during boot and grub related issues. But I get that line on my desktop screen, GUI.

UPDATE: It happens only if I'm using the highest resolution (1920x1080).

Comment: I had a white line at the top of my monitor until I changed my resolution.  Changing it back to the same thing, the line is still gone.

Answer (score 0):

I am just posting this as an answer since @Lotus didn't post it as an answer. What lotus suggested totally worked for me on Fedora Workstation 29 with gnome-shell, bumblebee, nvidia drivers and wayland. Switchting resolution to something else, and then back again removed the blinking white line at the top (left) of the screen.