# Ubuntu Bionic 18.04 flashing white line at top of onitor

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, themes, displayport

This problem is visible with a window whose edge is dark and is placed at the top of the monitor.

The problem only appears on my external DisplayPort monitor.  It doesn't appear on the laptop's own display or an HDMI display.

The DisplayPort monitor runs at 2560x1440 resolution and the HDMI and laptop display run at 1920x1080.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the theme.  I used Gnome Tweaks to change the theme from Ambiance to Radiance.

Of course, perhaps the problem is still there, but simply not visible because of the light window border.

This has also been described in 14.04 here: [Small white line flashing top of screen Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529575/small-white-line-flashing-top-of-screen-ubuntu-14-04)
but answers have been disabled on that question.